# How to call Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration::EnableDHCP() for a specific adapter in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wmi

One of my tasks it to configure network adapters for DHCP/static IP, and the only way I found to do this is using `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class.

WMI is new to me, and it seems to use it in C++ (Qt/MinGW) is not that easy, and most things I found in the WWW deal with .NET, PowerShell or VBScript. However, I already succeeded in querying information, for example the MAC address for a specific adapter.

I already read the *[MSDN: Calling a Provider method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* on MSDN, but in looking forware to `WIn32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` there is one thing I don't unstand.

My IEnumWbemClassObject is the result of a `SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE InterfaceIndex=n` (n is a number, of course), and returns `IWbemClassObject` for the specific adapter.

How to I tell ExecMethod which instance of `Win32_NetworkAdapterConiguration` to use when calling the `EnableDHCP()`/`EnableStatic()` methods (in meaning of the `IWbemClassObject` I will recieve when i enumerate the result of my query)?

Comment: Pass the IWBemClassObject interface pointer you have through the pInParams argument of the ExecMethod() function.  Well demonstrated in [code sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It tried this, but that didn't worked (returned error WBEM_E_INVALID_METHOD_PARAMETERS), which may relay on the fact that the sample calls the Method on "ClassName" (which was defined as Win32_Process).

After some additional search if found {this article](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/07/calling-instance-methods-in-wmi/) which tells to use **IBWbemClassObject::Get()** and query **__PATH**, and pass the path into the first parameter (object path) of the ExecMethod() function. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

While looking for a example for passing string arrays to ExecMethod() if found [this thread at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/387500/Cplusplus-WMI-EnableStatic-with-multiple-IPs) which execatly fit to my tasks. As stated in the comments above, the path of the object instance (not the class path!) must be passed to the "strObjectPath" parameter of ExecMethod.